# Maximum number of elements in array A that can be reduced to 1 by using operation at most K times

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

You have an array A of length N. you can perform an operation (you can perform the operation multiple times) on the elements of the array A.In the operation you can divide any element by its smallest factor greater than 1. You will be given Q tasks.In each task, you will be given an integer K and you have to tell the maximum number of elements in array A that can be reduced to 1 by using the operation at most K times.

**Input:**

First line contains two space-separated integers, N and Q.

Second line contains N space separated integers denoting the elements of array A.

Next Q lines contain an integer each, denoting the value of K.

**Output:**

For each task, print the answer of the t<sup>th</sup> task in new line.

```
Example Input:                          Example Output:
3 3                                     1
8 9 12                                  3
3                                       0
10
1

Explanation:
Number of operations required are 3,2,3 respectively.
For the first task, we can reduce any one of the three elements to 1.
For second task, we can reduce all the elements of the array to 1.
For third task, we cannot reduce any elements to 1.
```

Comment: Can you also post the value range for n and q, because then it will be more easier to build my code accordingly

Comment: @zenwraight, 1<=N<= 10^6  , 1<=Q<=10^5 , 1<= Ai<=10^6 , 1<=K<=10^6

Comment: So this answer has been put on hold, you should try posting ur question here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com and post the url of the quesiton here, I can answer it

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my english.

At first, you shuold build an Sieve of Eratosthenes, but instead of a boolean one, save the information on it of the smaller prime that divides the number, for example:

```
for (int i=4; i < MAXN; i+=2) sieve[i] = 2;
for (int i=3; i < MAXN; i+=2){
   if (!sieve[i]) for (int j=i*i; j <= MAXN; j+=2*i){
       if (!sieve[j]) sieve[j] = i;
}  }
```

Then, using the sieve you may easy and optimal build an array B containing the number of operations needed for each element in A. After that, sort array B and you may use binary search to answer the queries.